# How to connect MySQL to Java program

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I ve installed MySQL (last update). 
I need to code, that ll create & establish a connection with SQL DB
& manage the DB(using SELECT, INSERT, CREATE).

I did everything but, I am not able to create connection. I've also installed the MySQL/J connector, I just extracted the `.zip` pack in a folder & added the folder path in *Variables*).

Can anyone tell me wat is meant by URL in the below line?

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

I ve tried this:

```
String url = "jdbc:odbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/myfirstdb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "1234");
```

But it's not working. I am unable able to understand the term 'URL'.
Can anyone explain, the meaning of 'url' and wat should be done to connect to a SQL server from Java.

---

**Update:**

This is the Full code. It still cannot connect.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");//This s wat actually i did for connection
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded Succesfully");
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Unable to Load Driver!!!");
}

try {
    Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // initialise the driver
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myfirstdb";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "1234");
    System.out.println("connection Established");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Couldnt get connection");
    }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me wat is the purpose of MySQL Connector/J?

Comment: @Zaki, @Tamil Vendhan [has stated below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377151/how-to-connect-a-sql-server-to-java-program/3377265#3377265) that MySql is being used. I have added the mysql tag to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question you seem to be using a MySQL jdbc driver with a SQL Server jdbc URL.  This won't work.

If you are using a [MySQL](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm) database:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // initialise the driver

String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myfirstdb";
```

If you are using a SQL Server database you are going to need a completely different jdbc driver.  [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) is open source and a good option.  Include the jtds.jar file in your classpath and use something like:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  // initialise the driver

String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/myfirstdb";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extract from your code:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Couldnt get connection");
}
```

You should **never** suppress exceptions as long as you don't *understand* its cause. Replace it by at least:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Could not get connection");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or maybe

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not get connection", e);
}
```

Either way, you should see the exception type, message and trace. In your code snippet the possible exceptions are `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException`. The first one would mean that the driver is not properly placed in the classpath. The second one would mean that connection cannot be obtained. The exception message and/or trace should tell in detail about the underlying root cause of the problem.

You should always observe exceptions. They tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once a cause is **understood**, the solution is nothing more than obvious :)

#### See also:

- [Short MySQL/JDBC tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) - Contains explanation about exception causes.

---

Further,

> Can anyone tell me wat is meant by URL in the below line?

An URL is an [Uniform Resource Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). It's a common way to locate (identify) unique resources in computer systems and networks. The URL syntax for the MySQL database is explained in the [documentation of the JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

> Can you tell me wat is the purpose of MySQL Connector/J?

It's the JDBC driver. The [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) exist of almost only **interfaces**. The DB vendors should provide their own concrete JDBC API implementation, which is the JDBC driver. With a JDBC driver you'll be able to connect a specific database using JDBC API.

Answer (score 2):

If its MS SQL Server,

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://host:1433/database";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
```

For more info, see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100) to get started with Microsoft JDBC.

You can use any of the two JDBC drivers for MSSQL:

- [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 
  2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99b21b65-e98f-4a61-b811-19912601fdc9&displaylang=en)
- [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

For MS SQL Server driver 2.0, use

```
URL: jdbc:sqlserver://server:port; DatabaseName=dbname
Class name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

For MySql & Java, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a " at `Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
It should be

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: It happened 5 years ago, dude. Anyway, thanks for your answer. :-)