# How to communicate with MySQL from java

Tags: java, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect MySQL to Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377151/how-to-connect-mysql-to-java-program)

Hi I have some data that I would like to input into a MySQL server. However the data is being generated by a program I wrote in java. Is it possible to access and write to a MySQL server using java?

Comment: Anything is possible. You just have to write the code. :)

Comment: Yes it's possible and in fact much has been written about this including several well-written tutorials that you can easily find with Google. What have you found? What confuses you in particular? We do much better answering more specific questions, and we usually value evidence of effort made prior to asking a question. I suspect that most of the "answer" you will find here are not much more than Google substitutes, something you should really have done yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, if I was you I would check out mysql's own site where they also have a tutorial for all you need to know to get started http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with JDBC.  You will need to download the [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes with JDBC instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you big time if you have no experience what so ever:

[Installing MYSQL Connector/J JDBC on Microsoft Windows](http://primeroblogmio.blogspot.com/2010/08/installing-mysql-connectorj-jdbc-on.html)

and then follow the instructions from the JDBC tutorials.

Good luck!